# How does levels work in Log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am learning Log4j and I am trying to understand why it prints the debug message twice?
I have read about the additivty, and understand that the logging will propogate to the parent, which in this case would be "root". However the level on the "root" is fatal, so shouldn't this logging request be filtered?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="dataAccessLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="conversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.supertrooper">
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="dataAccessLogger" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="fatal" />
        <appender-ref ref="dataAccessLogger" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Code:

```
// Field in class
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log4JTesting.class);

// How I use it
logger.debug("Hello world!-----------------");
```

Comment: Stop right there. Rather use SLF4J + Logback. Log4J is legacy.

Comment: (3 Years later) : It's right. log4j 1.2 is legacy. But logback and log4j2 use the same mechanic. So this question is timeless I think ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `com.supertrooper` logger will inherit the appender from the root logger so you don't need to add the same appender explicitly to a child logger. If you do so, as in your example, then you'll end up getting duplicated messages.

The fact that the root logger is set to "fatal" doesn't change the fact that it's appenders will be inherited by children (whatever log level they're set for). If you want an appender to log only fatal messages regardless of which logger they came from, then you need to set a threshold on the *appender* itself.